# Function in python

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a Linear congruential generator in python and I find a little piece of [code on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Sample_Python_code) but have some difficulty on understanding it. The code is as follows:

```
def lcg(modulus, a, c, seed=None):
    if seed != None:
        lcg.previous = seed
    random_number = (lcg.previous * a + c) % modulus
    lcg.previous = random_number
    return random_number / modulus
lcg.previous = 2222
```

My problem is that what is "`lcg.previous`"? I notice that the function is done, the value of `lcg.previous` gets updated and stored. Is it declared as a member variable of function lcg() here or actually some kind of default set up for all function in python?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you can give the reference of where you found that code snippet.

Comment: I guess you did not copy all the relevant code, and lcg.previous is set to a starting value directly after the function definition.

Comment: Sorry about this, I happen to upload the my edited version. Thanks for editing.

Comment: I wonder if this is very old code. A much better way of achieving this would be with generators, but maybe this was written before they were available.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah, it is a very old way to generate a uniform random variable

Comment: What Python version is this?  The code fails for me in both 2.7 and 3.5 -- and this is a neat language feature!

Comment: @Prune Sorry, you need to assign a value to lcg.previous first, I missed that line of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a "member variable" of the function, so that each time it is called (except when called with something for `seed`) the sequence will pick of where it left off.

Comment: +1. As a note, with this you can emulate the behaviour of `static` function variables common in other languages, like C.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Python is recognizing the lcg.previous as a new variable declaration, and will add it as a member to lcg.

Comment: Python doesn't have variable declarations.

Comment: It does, it's just implied. the line <code>lcg(modulus, a, c, seed=None):</code> has implied local variable declaration of modulus, a, c, and seed. the line lcg.previous is an implied declaration of a member variable. Python just abstracts away the gritty part of declaring variables under the hood.

Comment: Python, the language, doesn't have a variable declarations. Variables [spring into existence](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) when they are assigned to. The language construct of variable declaration simply doesn't exist in Python, as it does in C, C++, Java etc. There is only assignment in Python. You are playing loose with terminology.

Comment: Variable declaration is either explicit or implicit.

Most compilers interpret an assignment statement as purely an assignment of a value to a memory location. If there is no memory location associated with the reference, you'll at worst get a run time exception, or at best a compiler exception.

Python sees that you are trying to use "seed", knows it doesn't have a memory address for it already, so it assigns one for you. Python operates under the assumption that your attempt to use a reference implies that you want the reference to actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

The `previous` variable is a property on the `lcg` function. In this example it's being used as a static variable for the `lcg` function. Since Python doesn't require variables (or object members) to be declared before use you can create them at need. In this case, you've create a member `previous` of the `lcg` function object.